# HAProxy 2.5 http-request replace-path not working correctly

Tags: redirect, web-config, haproxy

I need to have 301 redirect from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and from [www.example.com/fr](http://www.example.com/fr) to [www.example.com/fr/eshop](http://www.example.com/fr/eshop)

My  haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log stdout format raw local0

defaults
    log         global
    mode        http
    option      dontlognull
    option      http-ignore-probes
    log-format  "%ci:%cp [%tr] %ft %b/%s %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta %ST %B %CC %CS %tsc %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq %hr %hs %{+Q}r"
    option      forwardfor
    timeout     connect 30s
    timeout     client 30s
    timeout     server 30s

frontend http
    bind *:8080

    # redirect to www
    http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.example.com%[capture.req.uri] if { hdr(host) -i example.com }

    ### ACLs AND REDIRECTS ###
    acl path_de path_beg /de
    acl path_fr path_beg /fr
    acl path_fr_eshop path_beg /fr/eshop
    http-request replace-path /fr(.*) /fr/eshop\1 if path_fr !path_fr_eshop
    use_backend de if path_de
    use_backend fr if path_fr
    default_backend de

backend de
    http-request set-header Host www.example.com
    server de-gw 91.X.X.X:443 check ssl verify none

backend fr
    http-request set-header Host www.example.com
    server fr-gw 10.X.X.X:80
```

With this config redirect from non-www to www works fine

This also works fine: [www.example.com/fr](http://www.example.com/fr) is getting redirected to [www.example.com/fr/eshop](http://www.example.com/fr/eshop)

but [www.example.com/fr/](http://www.example.com/fr/) is getting redirected to [www.example.comfr/eshop/fr](http://www.example.comfr/eshop/fr)

I tried with following below replace-path:

```
http-request replace-path ^/fr(/|$)(.*) /fr/eshop\1\2 if path_fr !path_fr_eshop
```

but it did not help behavior is the same, /fr/ is getting redirected to /fr/eshop/fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evetything works OK with following replace-path:

```
http-request replace-path /(.*) /fr/eshop if path_fr !path_fr_eshop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).